# Is php a scalable language for web?

Tags: php

I have heared that PHP is not good for large websites althogh I do not know what is the meaning of large websites in this case, is it something like Facebook for example? Any way, is it true that PHP does scale with large websites?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is PHP apt for high-traffic websites?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319701/why-is-php-apt-for-high-traffic-websites)

Answer (score 13):

PHP is as scalable as the developer is proficient.

[Languages, libraries and frameworks don't scale. Architectures do.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1588617/php-vs-python-scalability/1588736#1588736)

Comment: That link/quote sums up scalability perfectly.

Comment: the link is dead now

Answer (score 2):

Yes, maybe not as inherently as some others (I'm a PHP developer).

http://swik.net/PHP/Major+Sites+that+use+PHP

Facebook is the biggest example, but there are many other ones as well.

Comment: Yeah but facebook faced a probelm with scalability so they released HipHop or extend php with C++ as I have read.

Comment: @user509953: Yes they did.  But only **after** they entered the top 10 list for traffic on the net.  They spent the majority of their time oh PHP...  It's only relatively recently that they've switched to the compiled version (past year or two)...

Comment: So can you give me a hint, when does PHP become not scalable? or let's say I have a server and run a PHP website on it (one server) how many visits the PHP will stand per day?

Comment: @user509953 exactly [42](http://www.google.com/search?q=the+answer+to+life%2C+the+universe+and+everything) unless you specify your server specs and provide the code you intent to run on it among other details required to determine that number.

Comment: @user509953: When the point that adding more hardware becomes more expensive than adding more developers...  Considering a decent developer salary of $80000 per year, and a team of at least 2 devs required to port and maintain the compiled version (which is a low estimate for a site of that size), you're talking $160k per year in hardware cost savings alone to justify the switch.  And considering $160k per year is about 320 good servers, you'd need to have enough traffic where you can **SAVE** 320 servers by switching.  And that's a BOAT load of traffic (Alexa top 50 at least)...

Comment: Is it the same case with ASP.NET/C#?

Comment: @user509953: Almost.  With ASP.NET, it's not as easy to port to a non-asp language.  So you will be forced to rewrite the application to make it native to get any kind of benefit.  And this is NOT something that 2 devs can do quickly for any kind of complex site (not to mention licensing).  At least with PHP, you can build c level extensions to PHP to "migrate" towards a more complied site, then simply run Hip-Hop on it to build your binary.  But PHP will scale much better than a lot of other languages for the simple fact that you can load-balance it very easily...

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to differ with my counterparts here. As a language, nothing about PHP is built for scalability. Any language can be extended for that, and PHP has far more than its fair share of tools to do it, but as far as built-in tools to support that need, it has none.

Which is exactly what makes it a great choice.

You see, with the lack of built-in high-level web tools, it allows others to built unique solutions to the problems. Just about every major advancement in other languages has been duplicated for PHP. There is not a single tool out there in some other language that isn't matched or beat by something in PHP.

And after all that, those built-in limitations help foster good development practices and security-conscious designs. It forces we devs to learn the theory behind the techniques we apply and cuts-down on the misapplication of those principals.

Anyway. /lovemaking-with-php

Answer (score 0):

PHP is fairly scalable, and certain frameworks such as Zend increase the likelihood of successful scalability.

The biggest obstacle to scalability in PHP has less to do with the language or its framework and more to do with programming and system architecture in general. Developing a good, scalable system is difficult even for the masters.

Answer (score 0):

A programming language cannot always be pinpointed as THE culprit in problems related to performance. How it's used and what environment it's running in should be considered and must go thru any honest-to-goodness performance audit. PHP is definitely scalable, but the more important things you should consider: application efficiency, disk I/O, bandwidth management, etc. You may have the perfect high-traffic capable application, but try running it on an old PC or a dial-up modem.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your application architecture not programming languages. If your architecture and design is optimised your application will perform very well on large scale. And also depends on your servers.