# What are the architectural limitations of PHP?

Tags: php, architecture

I was reading the article ["PHP Sucks, But It Doesn't Matter"](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/05/php-sucks-but-it-doesnt-matter.html) by Jeff Atwood.

In the comments he writes:

> That said, I absolutely think it's important for PHP devs to be aware of the architectural limitations of PHP, and understand the alternatives.

What are those limitations and how do they compare with other scripting / weakly typed languages?

Also, what are the alternatives in those conditions where limitations need to be avoided?

Comment: I just read the first two paragraphs, but as far as I can see: You can ignore the article, because its bad. The first argument is that there are many functions starting with "a", but he completely ignores, that most of them are group by the prefix ("pseudo-namespace") and also grouped within the manual. The whole article goes on by wrapping his own indifferent oppinion into a kind of "article".

Comment: I wouldn't consider poor organization of functions an "architectural limitation," etc. Those types of things are just annoyances. Ultimately they do not affect what you can do with the language.

Comment: @KingCrunch: Do you realize that "he" is [co-founder and CTO](http://stackexchange.com/about/team) of StackOverflow/StackExchange?

Comment: @coreyward Why is that worth mentioning? Nobody should self-censor just because their opinions run counter Jeff's, and Jeff isn't automatically right because he founded Stack Overflow.

Comment: I would vote to close if I could, this has been debated ad infinitum...

Comment: Some possibly related information: [Why is PHP apt for high traffic websites](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319701/why-is-php-apt-for-high-traffic-websites/3319785#3319785)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There are basically two real limitations I see:

**PHP is a fully synchronous language**. This has impact on which things you can easily implement in PHP and which not. For example implementing a [Long Polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling) driven chat application isn't trivial, because PHP would need block one process per chatter. I'm not saying it's impossible, you can hack around this limitation using some PHP Daemon library. I'm just saying that this is one of the cases where other languages, like JavaScript, are more appropriate ([NodeJS](http://nodejs.org/)).

**PHP is slow**. Please don't understand this an an offense. It's a fact that PHP - as implemented by Zend - is slow compared to other scripting languages. This typically is no problem when building websites, but you obviously can't do certain things: Implementing a ray tracer in PHP is definitely a bad idea - whereas in JavaScript you could do this.

But apart from that, I think that PHP is pretty multi-purpose. You can use it for nearly anything - and I do ;)

Comment: If a language is slow maybe you are doing something wrong. Javascript isn't faster then php. It's because Google made it fast!

Comment: @epitaph: That's why I said "PHP - as implemented by Zend - is slow". I know that there are alternative PHP implementations, like the one from Facebook, that are faster (but have other drawbacks). But normally, if people say "PHP" they mean Zend's PHP. PS: It is really unfair to say that Chrome made JavaScript fast. The JS engines of all modern browser are nearly equally fast, one better at this benchmark, the other better at the other.

Comment: PHP isn't slow, what's slow is the PHP interpreter that interprets it into bytecode. Language itself *is* fast. Run a test with APC, you'll notice extreme speed increase. As for JS engines - sadly, V8 IS faster than all the other JS engines, Firefox JS engine is still slow, IE cheats on tests and out of all of them only V8 does garbage collection properly.

Comment: @Michael: APC only makes it slightly faster because it saves you the tokenization, parsing and opcode-compilation. It still leaves you with opcode-interpretation, which, compared to JS, is still very slow. Furthermore: Your statement that V8 is faster than FFs statement is only partially true. Sure, Google beats Firefox on the V8 benchmark - well, it's their own benchmark after all -, but will be slower for example on Mozilla's own benchmark Kraken. So, yes, Google is faster than Mozilla, but Mozilla is also faster than Google :)

Comment: @nikic - nope, it's not "slightly" faster, it's much faster when used with APC - proven by many tests and observed by many developers - including myself and my coworkers. On the other hand, there is an option of creating an actual executable and bypassing the php virtual machine all together. As for my statement that V8 is faster than FF - it is, there's no doubt about it, real world use of Chrome confirms it (along with benchmarks) since everything actually *is* faster when viewed with Chrome.

Comment: @MichealJ.V. Be very careful when you say that Chrome or FF or IE9 is faster then the other. [This benchmark from crockford](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/performance.html) actually shows IE10 is 5 times as fast as chrome. There is no fastest browser anymore. There are just certain things V8 is better at and certain things chakra is better at and certain things JeagerMonkey is better at.

Answer (score 20):

Take a look at the date. The article was written in 2008.

It means, that if you'll see the PHP5.3 advantages, you'll find there many things, like closures and namespaces, which were in other languages before. Some of them is already affected the architecture of famous frameworks, like Symfony.

And that list will never be complete.

---

Meanwhile, I meet a lot of people who think that "weak typing" language is an architectural problem itself.

Then, some people think that inline regex syntax is good thing in, for example, JavaScript, but others think, that "different language" must be written down in string constants there, as in PHP. Etc.

Answer (score 15):

I'll take a stab at this without getting too into the nitty gritty:

- The initial design of PHP as a collection of functions still shows through.
- Object-oriented patterns that have been implemented in the latest PHP 5 releases are still half-baked and lack multiple inheritance (or "mixins"), proper module support, and are designed to be backwards compatible with the CoF (collection of functions) design.
- Method overriding and callbacks are not supportive natively.
- Closures. They are there, but they are very weak.
- Errors vs Exceptions — methods are inconsistent in which they use (thanks again to CoF design), and error-handling is half-baked.

I'm sure I'm stepping on someone's toes here and I'll get any angry mob, but I'm also sure that I still didn't hit everything. It's largely subjective, but it's easy to see what is to dislike when you stack PHP up next to Ruby or Python.

Comment: "Multiple inheritance" is _explicitly_ omitted and therefore _no_ design, or archituectural issue. "Method overriding" and "callbacks" _are_ supported. "Closures" works as defined, dont know what you mean by "weak". And last but not least: "Errors" come from the core, Exceptions from higher level code. At some points it feels strange, but they are not inconsistent like you said. However, your first argument is valid :)

Comment: Multiple inheritance is omitted from Ruby too, but it's replaced by mixins, which beat the shit out of confuzzled multiple inheritance messes. Have a link to docs on PHP supporting method overriding and callbacks natively?

Comment: @coreyward, what do you mean by callbacks? `$foo = function(){}; $foo()` works. Method overriding works as expected... Do you mean overloading? That too is supported, but only through some ugly calls to functions like `func_get_args()`.

Comment: To address some of your other complaints: PHP 5.4 will support "traits" (basically auto copy/paste) which is similar to mixins. You can easily set up an error handler to throw exceptions for those older functions that don't do that. Yes, PHP is ugly, but with a little self discipline, it's not too bad.

Comment: @coreyward: #callback: http://php.net/language.pseudo-types#language.types.callback As you can see you have the possibility to use nearly everything, that is callable, as a callback. #override: Extend the class and override it. Its like in any other oop language. Dont get, whats the matter :?

Comment: @konforce: `func_get_args()` is for arbitrary parameter count. You either mean the magic method `__call()` or the fact, that there is (usually) no type hint and a method can decide how it behaves on the type of the arguments given.

Comment: @KingCrunch: I suppose the "method" overriding I'm speaking of is without a hack — you should be able to redefine any method/function, without extending the class. This becomes a complete mess. There are extensions to PHP that let you do this.

Comment: @coreyward: Overwriting methods on a defined class is itself a hack. It doesnt feel like a good design, if you need to hack around into your classes to get them working. I know, its part of some concepts (like JSs prototype-oop), but PHP instead prefers the "clean" oop approach. However, you can achieve a similar behaviour with `__call()`.

Comment: I think the discussion here can be summarized with PHP is not a thoroughly object-oriented language by design. PHP is more a string-centric VM, and basic types and identifiers can not double as objects (and so have prototypical callbacks like in Python). -- That language semantic is partly what the "architectural limitations" refer to. But I guess it was more about the PHP runtime and one process per request operation model. Even though Zend extensions make PHP objectively more flexible than other languages.

Comment: @coreyward Your answer assumes "OOP = good" and concludes with "like/dislike", which does not answer architectual limitations and alternatives objectively.

Comment: @Mel No it doesn't. Closures are a huge benefit of modern languages, irrespective of whether a language is object-oriented. Ditto with decent error/exception handling. PHP is a procedural language with strong support for server-side script interpretation invoked by an HTTP request & server. Ruby and Python (for example) are both designed with more general purposes in mind and have great web-request handling frameworks available. Which architecture seems more flexible? OOP has little to do with the matter.

Comment: It is actually flexibility that is the main architectural problem of PHP. Because you can use it procedurally and OOP there is a lot of pollution. No standard is enforced for including 'modules', so one can not expect any convention by 3rd party code. This is what other languages do better. Perl, python, ruby all have import constructs that map module to filename ensuring no duplicates can exist. This flexibility is the main problem when developing projects with 3rd party code, and it's main strength when developing without as you can adhere to your own rules. The facilities are there.

Comment: All reasons looks like 'I don't understand how it works, so it's ugly'.

Answer (score 14):

I don't find it odd anymore that all of "PHP SUCKS" articles are coming from developers accustomed to established Microsoft technologies.

What I do find odd are statements that indicate that PHP is a spaghetti code. It's **completely up to the author** of the code whether the code will be spaghetti or if it'll use certain design rules when approaching the problem.

The reason a lot of PHP code out there is spaghetti code is because examples and tutorials are such that they don't teach beginners the good coding practices. Also, people are quick to grasp examples like `hello world` or connecting to MySQL, doing a query and looping over the result - but that's it, that's where **ALL** tutorials stop. I still haven't found a tutorial that covers the following:

- what is a framework and what it helps with
- what are data structures and data types (explained in a way a normal human can understand)
- what is an array, what are array dimensions, how do arrays work, what are arrays useful for
- what is object oriented code, why object oriented code, how does PHP do it, what is considered good, why are there patterns out there and so on

As you can see, a beginner programmer won't be bothered to learn all of those points outlined above, I know that because I was a beginner too and did all the mistakes beginners do. However, even if someone doesn't know how to program, they can still create useful applications.

Many popular scripts were written by people who knew **WHAT** they want to achieve, however they did not know **HOW** to properly design the environment (framework) in which they'll deploy their php code.
That's why we see scripts that become incredibly popular due to the ease of their use as a regular user which are hard to extend looking at it as a developer, using weird function names, odd coding conventions and no commenting.

Also, what's ridiculous is saying PHP is slow which is absolute nonsense. When I come across such statement, I want to shoot myself in the head for reading such a blog entry.

### One has to know several things before making such a statement:

- PHP is a scripting language, that means the interpreter is invoked every time someone requests a PHP page which takes **A LOT** of CPU power. That has been addressed by using bytecode caching mechanisms such as [APC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php) which stores the copy of pre-interpreted piece of the script in memory. The results are impressive, and I kid you not - execution for some of my scripts goes from 20 milliseconds to 1 microsecond, where some benefit "only" 5 times. That's on a system that serves 1 thousand concurrent users. Now, if someone wants to tell me that 1 microsecond is slow (or 5 milliseconds) - I'll take that as bullshit.
- PHP is not the only thing involved in serving a web page. There's also underlying server (Apache) which has its own issues, there's MySQL which runs queries - and who says all queries are optimal? There's the network, there's the hard disk, there's the CPU, there are tons of other processes. Configure Apache with PHP-FPM, optimize MySQL to perform good on 8 core machine with 16 gigs of ram, use APC, use Memcache - and voila, you're getting an incredibly fast, scalable system capable of serving an incredible amount of traffic.
  Languages that PHP is being compared to are often "compiled" into the bytecode and then executed by
- You can extend PHP yourself. Assuming a PHP function is slow, NOTHING prevents anyone from creating a .so in C that is able to do the job faster and then hooking everything up trough extension in PHP. Not that I know what would such job be that would require that, but such a thing IS possible.

Sadly, and I say sadly because I respect certain programmers and admire their work (and I'm by no means a PHP fanboy) but it hurts me when I see uneducated, inexperienced and subjective comments about a tool which spreads misinformation.

As for why big websites use PHP - because it's fast. Because they laid proper foundations before starting the projects. Because it's free, extensible and scalable. Because it follows C syntax. Because you can extend it when you need it to be faster. Because it runs on a free operating system. Because it's easy to use.

Comment: This entire answer can be summed up in the article written by Jeff. PHP sucks (use Ruby, Python, Scala, Clojure, Haskell, Erlang, etc. and you'll understand), but it doesn't matter — it'll still be used to great effect.

Comment: So if I use <Ruby for example>, my source code is prone to spaghetti code? It's faster? I can quickly write a C extension and call the functions from .so if I want to speed up execution of certain things? I can compile it to a binary? Also, why do you even comment on my post if you didn't read it at all and bothered to absorb what I tried to say?

Comment: 1) What? 2) You can use C in Ruby, without recompiling anything or writing extensions. 3) You can compile Ruby just about as well as you can compile PHP, which is not very. I did read your answer and understood it well, I just think you're missing the point of Jeff's blog post.

Answer (score 3):

PHP is improving everyday. It is open source and used all around the world. That said, when you have a problem, it is most probable that you will find your solution or get help faster than any other language.

The very reason of this article, I believe it is simple. If you (or in that matter any other programmer) used to code in C++, Java etc.. they had a lot of possibilities such as OOP coding and PHP was limited in the beginning.

It is a good thing that PHP has many built-in functions / methods / classes so you don't have to spend hours to code some function / class / method which PHP already has.

You don't have to (and you shouldn't) try to memorize all these functions. It is useless to memorize all of them (which one is doing what, how to use it etc). Imagine you are working on some project which took you 4-5 months to finish (yeah big one (: ) You are not going to use all these functions in all the projects and eventually you will forget what they were doing since you don't use them often.

The point is, you should know the syntax of PHP. When you need to do something, check first if PHP already has what you want to do in its library. Check the manual to see how to use it. This way, you will also **LEARN** (NOT MEMORIEZE) the ones you use often and this information will be hard to forget.

PHP or any other programming language is just like a normal language which we humans use daily to communicate with each other. If you don't use it, you will forget.

PHP 5.3 and above brought many features. Static feature is one of the biggest feature for me. It made my life so much easier that I can't even begin to describe.

Since PHP is that famous and open source web scripting language, Facebook developer team created [**HipHop**](https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/wiki/).

What HipHop does is, takes the data from PHP and sends it to C++. C++ does all the process and sends back results to PHP for outputting.

The whole idea of HipHop was to make Facebook use less servers & improve the page display times.

Now you tell me if this seems limited and / or slow to you?

Comment: HIPPO PHP what a joke. PHP can be extended with extensions in C. What is the point to use HIPPO and C#? And also Facebook is just looking like a polish version of myspace. It's slow, bad interface, It's not fancy at all!

Comment: If I like it or not to use facebook, I personally think they achieved something great on cyber world which myspace couldn't even get close to. This is also another example the point of using C#. You have to keep yourself up to date to follow new technologies. If facebook were a country, would be 3rd biggest in the world, what about myspace? Did they get close to what FB has now? They didn't bring any new ideas but FB did. That's why I don't see it as a Joke.

Comment: Myspace have had more potential then FB. Even the name is better and FB was some stolen script at the beginning. Think of napster it was only used by noobs.

Comment: Different point of views (: It still doesn't change the fact what is FB today.I just like to support people / projects which have new ideas. Japan was hiring people with imagination to create new ideas, later asking the scientists to make it real. No wonder why technologically they are more advance then any other country. Such supportive approaches are just helpful to everyone, it is not harmful.

Comment: HIPPOPHP and C# ? can you provide any link that support you theory ? as I remember it wac compiling to C not C#

Comment: HIPHOP analyzes bytecode and transforms it to highly optimized c++ code that is then compiled with g++. Works only on 64 bit machines and EVAL() cannot be used.

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/wiki/ - yes, it is true. Would you be so kind and refrain yourself from posting misinformation and actually learn something before you involve yourself in a discussion? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

i dont think there is anything like 'architectural limitation' for php. developer knowledge limitation might be the reason. read this http://www.quora.com/What-is-Facebooks-architecture . most of the time, non-world-class developer does not know how they could use php to its full capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume he is referring to the fact the the OOP portions of PHP are not the greatest compared to languages that are purely object oriented.

Answer (score 0):

Architecture Limitations in Addition to [nikic's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5823310/what-are-the-architectural-limitations-of-php/5861576#5861576)

**Writing extensions for PHP** is a PITA.  Not as bad as with Perl or Java, but not as easy as it could be.  The ease of extensibility champion is still TCL which hails from the early 90's. Nearly any C function taking char* can be made into a TCL extension.

**Embedding PHP in other systems.** mod_php, gtk.php.net shows it can be done, but Guile and TCL are much easier to embed.

Comment: +1 for TCL, the most easily embedded language ever written.