# How to scale PHP

Tags: php, scalability

I'm creating a new web application in PHP and I'd like to create it in a way that scales well over time.

What should or shouldn't I do? I know that I should cache, but what should I cache and how? What else can I do for the website to remain loading rapidly?

Comment: If scalability is the main goal of you web app, you should at least once think about why you chose PHP for doing so and not a language, that was build for that purpose. What benefits are there when you keep using PHP and why aren't you switching to Scala/Erlang/node.js or anything similar? Could HipHop (for PHP, not for your ears) help to improve your goal?

Comment: There's a good post about that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319701/why-is-php-apt-for-high-traffic-websites

Answer (score 28, accepted):

*Note: this wasn't written by me, but by [Snorkel from YC news](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=4070126)*

Here's a short list:

1. **Cache the output** at the edges: Use `Varnish` or other reverse proxy cache.
2. **Cache byte code**: Use `APC` or `XCache` PHP opcode cache.
3. **Cache and minimize database I/O**: reduce database touches using `memcached`, `redis`, file caches, and application-level caches (ie. global vars)
4. **Do event logging** in local files, not to the database: Make all write operations as simple and fast as possible, any data that is not needed in realtime can be written to a plain old file and processed later.
5. **Use a CDN**, especially for delivering static assets
6. **Server tuning**: `Apache`, `MySQL`, and `Linux` have lots of settings that affect performance, especially the timeout settings ought to be turned down.
7. **Identify bottlenecks**: At the system level use tools such `strace`, `top`, `iostat`, `vmstat`, and query logging to see which layer is using the most time and resources
8. **Load testing**: DoS yourself. Stress test your stack to find bottlenecks and tune them out
9. **Remove unused modules**: For each component in the stack unload any default modules that are not needed to deliver your service.
10. **Don't use ORMs** and other dummy abstractions: Take off the training wheels and write your own queries.
11. **Make the entry pages fast**, simple, and cacheable. Nobody is reading that silly news feed in bottom corner of your front page and it's killing your database, so take it out.

Most of the time a PHP slows down because each PHP process is blocked waiting for I/O from some other layer, either a slow disk, or overloaded database, or hung memcached process, or slow REST API call to a 3rd party service ... often just strace'ing a live PHP process will show you what its waiting for ... in short, blocking I/O slows down everything. The key to going faster is:

#### - keep it simple

#### - cache as much as possible in local memory

#### - do as few blocking I/O operations as possible per request

Answer (score 1):

Scaling to several front-ends require also to replicate the root of your website and its dynamic content.

GlusterFS is a nice add, however it is unclear to me how well it scales up. Another alternative is Lsyncd. Other alternatives may include GIT for the code and a CDN for the dynamic content.

Answer (score 0):

You should add: compress output with gzip.

Comment: This is definitely essential for site performance, but doesn't make much of a difference for scalability, since it doesn't have an effect on the server (well, it adds a very slight overhead for the compression, but that's negligible)